# ElectronJs: please install sqlite3 package manually

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I was trying to configure `sqlite` database with `electron` application and after install `sqlite` dependency I was start getting the error **please install sqlite3 package manually**. I repeat the same steps several time but `sqlite` doesn't work with the `electron`

I just search about this problem over the internet and I found couple of answer but each answer have missing steps. So After spend my 4 working days on this issue I come up with a solid solution with all detailed steps. Hopefully it can save the time for other

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are getting the error **cannot find node module sqlite3** or **please install sqlite3 package manually** in `electron` application after install `sqlite`. Then this solution can be help full to fix your issue.

**Step 1:** We need to clone electron quick start project on your local

Source: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app

```
$ git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
```

**Step 2:** Go into the repository

```
$ cd electron-quick-start
```

**Step 3:** Install electronJs dependencies

```
$ npm install
```

**Step 4:** Run electron project

```
$ npm start
```

Now lets come to most challenging part

**Step 5:** Now we need to install sqlite dependency

```
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
$ npm install sequelize --save
```

**Step 6:** Open main.js in your IDE and add this code at the end of file to create database connection

Source: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/usage.html

```
// Create database connection
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    operatorsAliases: false,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    },
    storage: './database.sqlite'
});

// Test connection
sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });
```

**Step 7:** Now again start your electron project using `npm start` and you will start getting exception

```
Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually
```

## How we can fix it?

**Step 8:** To fix this error we need to install electron-rebuild package. Make sure you are using cmd **run as Administrator** before execute this command otherwise it will never work.

```
$ npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

**Step 9:** Now we have to configure the rebuild command in `package.json` under the script

```
"scripts": {
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
}
```

**Step 10:** Now we Need to install python and set it into Path in environment variable.

- Download Python: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/
- Open Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Setting > Enviroment Variables
- Under **User variables for %username%** section click on new to add a new Item
- Set variable name `Path` and variable value `C:\Python27` (where you have installed python) and click on **OK** Button

**Step 10:** Now open a new command line and rebuild your electron project

```
$ npm run rebuild
```

**Step 11:** And now you can run it and it will works fine

```
$ npm start
```

Happy Programming.

---

**NOTE: If you will get this error on Step 10 while running `npm run rebuild`**

```
× Rebuild Failed

An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\sqlite3\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Projects\\Test\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=1.8.8" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Projects\\Test\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v1.8-win32-x64" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v4.0.2/{toolset}/" "--package_name=electron-v1.8-win32-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\\Projects\\Test\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1

Error: Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\sqlite3\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Projects\\Test\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=1.8.8" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Projects\\Test\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v1.8-win32-x64" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v4.0.2/{toolset}/" "--package_name=electron-v1.8-win32-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\\Projects\\Test\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1
    at SafeSubscriber._error (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:277:84)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:242:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:201:26)
    at Subscriber._error (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:132:26)
    at Subscriber.error (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:106:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:132:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:106:18)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:251:65)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:251:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (C:\Projects\Test\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:191:27)
```

Then execute this in command line `npm install windows-build-tools --global`

And while installing `windows-build-tools` if you will get this exception

```
async function aquireInstallers(cb) {
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\start.js:4:29)
```

It means you are using old version of nodeJS to fix it you can install old version of **windows-build-tools** using `npm install windows-build-tools@2.2.1 --global`

And now you can start the project using `npm start`

Comment: in some situation, also need to do `npm install -g windows-build-tools` [electron-rebuild failure with sqlite3 · Issue #204 · electron/electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild/issues/204)

Comment: Well structured answer.

Comment: Good answer, but in my case, I needed to do `npm install -g windows-build-tools --vs2015` (because the current version is 2017, but this isn't yet supported by node-gyp). It took a long time (maybe half an hour) with a medium-speed connection to perform the install.

Comment: Also, on my system (which is running Windows 10), I needed to add "C:\Users\[username]\.windows-build-tools\python27\" to Environment Variables > User variables > path, not "C:\python27".

Answer (score 2):

If you use sqlite3 via sequelize, you can avoid the error with adding sequelize to externals of webpack.config like this.

```js
module.exports = {
  // other configs ..
  externals: {
    "sequelize": "require('sequelize')",
  },
}
```

Reference: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/38723672-can-not-pack-sequelize-with-sqlite3

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using `dialectModule` option in `sequelize`.

```
// db.ts

import sqlite3 from "sqlite3"
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize"

const sequelize = new Sequelize( {
  dialect: "sqlite",
  dialectModule: sqlite3, // Set it here.
  storage: ":memory:",
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and, to solve it, i just change the node version.
I run at version 14.0.0 and got the error.
Then a change node version to 12.0.0 and everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

well, the sqlite3 module does need python version 2 installed to build, in case it cannot be found in binary form by node-pre-gyt.